# Add a twitter feed to my Wordpress website

Tags: widgets, sidebar, twitter

My website is [WilsonsTransportation](http://www.wilsonstransportation.com). On the left hand side of my site we have "testimonials" scrolling down. I've located the coding for that in my custom theme under `page-home.php`.

I was hoping to add a twitter feed underneath or above the testimonials that are showing. The code is quite long but I can post it if needed. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a widget area assigned at the left hand side, then there are many plugins for the purpose:

> - [Mini Twitter Feed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/mini-twitter-feed)
> - [WD Twitter Feed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wd-twitter-feed)
> - [Twitter Feed Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-feed-widget)
> - [Tweet Tweet Feed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/twitter-tweet-feed)
> - [Super Simple Twitter Feed](http://wordpress.org/plugins/super-simple-twitter-feed/)
> - [Really Simple Twitter Feed Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-twitter-feed-widget)
> - [Twitter Feed: Embedded Timeline WordPress Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-twitter-feed/)

Just install any of them from Plugins > Add New ... then install and set up reading the Installation manual.